# Set Picklist field to blank with Process Builder

Tags: process-builder

Is it possible to set a picklist to blank using Process Builder.  From what we can tell it just gives you an option of any of the picklist values, but wont let you save the value as blank?

Is there some other way to clear the value of a picklist field like that?

Comment: I think create a picker value of None or Blank and assign it .I think thats the only way i currently see .This looks like huge limitation

Comment: Seems like that's the only option, bummer.  If you want to post as an answer I can mark it as the correct one as it seems like the only option for now

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm a bit late to the party, but for future reference there's a $GlobalConstant.Null field that can be used for this:

[image: GlobalConstant.Null example]

Comment: Yup, looks like they added that as an option in the spring release and its a much better way to do it!  thanks for updating the answer

Comment: This is not working , values in my picklist is not getting changed to NONE

Comment: Check that the process is completing and that nothing is changing the field value afterwards. Take a look at what the debug logs show you is happening. Perhaps a validation rule, failed workflow, apex trigger etc is preventing the value from being set.

Comment: Thank you. This is super useful and worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Create a picker value of None or Blank and assign it .I think thats the only way i currently see .

Answer (score 1):

I tricked it by having the picklist come out to being a formula using this. Works great for me now and I can update picklist values.

IF( $User.Id = $User.Id, "" , "" )

Answer (score 0):

Note - they have also added a similar option for strings: $GlobalConstant.EmptyString.

Comment: This, to me, doesn't seem like an answer that stands on its own, but rather something that's better off as a comment on an existing answer. You can't comment on other people's posts until you hit 50 rep (unless a moderator converts this to a comment) though. If you can expand on this a bit more to help it stand on its own (by making an [edit]), that'd probably be the best outcome here.