# Setting lookup field to blank using Process Builder

Tags: lookup, process-builder

Pretty similar to [Set Picklist field to blank with Process Builder](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/66546/set-picklist-field-to-blank-with-process-builder), is it possible to do this for **lookup fields**? The only workarounds I'm seeing is doing this in a separate flow, which kind of offsets the advantages of doing a complete business logic in one visually clear process...

[image: Lookup field]

Comment: believe its limitation : here's an open idea for date fields but believe it applies to all non text fields - https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Dk1MAAS

Comment: Can you set it to null?

Comment: Not that I know of, leaving the box empty and saving just throws an error that a value is required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set a lookup field to blank or null by entering in 15 zeros

[image]

Answer (score 3):

My answer from the other post works here too; the process builder now supports usage of $GlobalConstant.Null on lookup fields.  For example, the Contact Owner lookup:

[image: GlobalConstant.Null field for contact owner ID]